# Excel VBA: How to detect that the printed width is greater than the printed height

Tags: excel, vba, printing, width, area

To autofit the print area to the sheet content, I'm using the following Excel 2010 VBA code:

```
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
```

that works. Now additionaly I would like to detect if the printed width is greater than the printed height, and then change to landscape printing. Something like this:

```
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1

    if .PrintedWidth > .PrintedHeight then      ' how to detect it?
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
    end if
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
```

How can I detect if the printed width is greater than the printed height?

I see that the PrintArea property is empty after autofitting, so I can't use it to detect the condition.

Comment: **Solved**: Just compare width and height of the ActiveSheet.UsedRange range:

    If ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Width > ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Height Then
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
    End If

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**: Just compare width and height of the ActiveSheet.UsedRange range:

```
If ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Width > ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Height Then
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
End If
```